# Range field for alpaca

Tags: range, alpacajs

I'm trying to get a handle on alpacajs and wanted to see if it would be a good fit for a project i am working one.
I have a few sliders (..) that I need to get on the forms.
Is that possible with Alpaca JS or do I need to customize the data somehow?
How would the range be represented in the schema?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this page http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/integer.html ? Is that what you wanted to do? (scroll down to example 2).

Comment: yes that was it.. thanks!

Comment: glad it helps. tell me if you need something else related to this question.